# Have for loop or a .forEach method remove the current array element, then have flow continue from from the same index?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

I am working on this problem from coderbytes:

*Using the JavaScript language, have the function SecondGreatLow(arr) take the array of numbers stored in arr and return the second lowest and second greatest numbers, respectively, separated by a space. For example: if arr contains [7, 7, 12, 98, 106] the output should be 12 98. The array will not be empty and will contain at least 2 numbers. It can get tricky if there's just two numbers!*

My solution works by removing the greatest and lowest values from the array and then using Math methods to return the second highest and lowest values.

However, when there are two or more instances of the greatest or lowest elements of the array, and their index positions are adjacent to each other, I believe only the first instance of this value is removed and the flow skips over the second instance.

**Is there any way to have the loop run through the same index value twice** in order to process adjacent greatest or lowest values?

Here are the two iterations of my solution which I've tested.. my original attempt using .forEach and my second using a for loop.. I've console.logged a situation in which the code works and in which it doesn't for each attempt.

I'm really new to all this, almost a month of learning in my free time so explaining yourself as if I'm really dumb is appreciated.  Thanks!!!

---

```
// * First attempt - using .forEach method *

// outputs the second lowest value in the array
function secondLowest (arr) {
    var g = function () {
        return Math.min.apply(null, arr);
    }
    arr.forEach(function (val, indx, arr) {
        if (val === g()) {
            arr.splice(indx, 1);
        }
    });
    lowestVal = g(); // store this value to be added back in for the secondGreatest function (in case there were only two digits in the arr argument)
    return Math.min.apply(null, arr);   
}


// number trimmed from the array in the function secondLowest.. 
// to be added back in for the function secondGreatest
var lowestVal = 0


// adds back the lowest value which was trimmed..
// outputs the second greatest value
function secondGreatest (arr){
    arr.splice(0,0,lowestVal);
    var g = function () {
        return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
    }
    arr.forEach(function (val, indx, arr) {
        if (val === g()) {
            arr.splice(indx, 1);
        }
    });
    return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
}


// putting together the output
function SecondGreatLow (arr) {
    return secondLowest(arr) + " " + secondGreatest(arr);
}
console.log(SecondGreatLow([1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(SecondGreatLow([1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]));
```

---

```
// * Second attempt - using for loops *

// outputs the second lowest value in the array
function secondLowest (arr) {
    var g = function () {
        return Math.min.apply(null, arr);
    }
    lowestVal = g();
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === g()) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);

        }
    }
    return Math.min.apply(null, arr);   
}


// number trimmed from the array in the function secondLowest.. 
// to be added back in for the function secondGreatest
var lowestVal = 0


// adds back the lowest value which was trimmed..
// outputs the second greatest value
function secondGreatest (arr){
    arr.splice(0,0,lowestVal);
    var g = function () {
        return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === g()) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
}


// putting together the output
function SecondGreatLow (arr) {
    return secondLowest(arr) + " " + secondGreatest(arr);
}
console.log(SecondGreatLow([1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(SecondGreatLow([1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]));
```

I tried using the delete operator in order to keep the argument array length consistent (rather than shortening it with splice which I think allows the adjacent value to pass into the removed element's index position and not be processed in the next runthrough of the for loop or forEach method) but the Math.min/max.apply methods don't like having 'undefined' in the array argument.

Also if my code is looking ugly/annoying and makes you cringe then please take this opportunity to vent.. helps me learn to write code that doesn't piss people off ;)

---

** Solution Found **
Thank you for reminding me of the sort method!(function?)  Here's what I ended up with:

```
function SecondGreatLow (arr) {
    var secondLow = 0,
        secondHigh = 0;
    arr.sort(function(a,b){
        return a-b;
    });
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] !== arr[i-1]) {
            secondLow = arr[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    for (var j = (arr.length-2); j >= 0; j--) {
        if (arr[j] !== arr[j+1]) {
            secondHigh = arr[j];
            break;
        }
    }
    return secondLow + " " + secondHigh;
}
console.log(SecondGreatLow([1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]));
```

What an awesome community.. I'll be back with more questions and hopefully I'll feel confident enough to even answer some questions in the near future.  Thanks!

Comment: What should only two numbers return? Like `[1,1]`?

Comment: Just sort it: it's trivial to return the result from the sorted array.

Comment: eelclanrs - yes, so if the input array was [1,2] then the output should be "2 1"

zerkms - one of the answers mentioned sort.. i just skimmed the first one and am gonna look at it closer.. I think I used sort once before, didn't think of it when I approached this problem. thanks!

Markus - The problem is the input numbers are not limited by anything so I can't expect a largest or smallest value.. it's a theoretical problem so the values are unbound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like perhaps I'm missing something, but the challenge doesn't seem to include a requirement for removing items from the original array, so I don't see why you're modifying it in such a way.  The requirements you provided simply state to return 'a b' where a is the second lowest, and b the second highest.

So, I would first recommend sorting the list.  Since you know you're working at the upper and lower bounds, you don't have to iterate over anything (nor should you).  Your test arrays are already sorted, but ensuring order will make your code more robust and able to handle other inputs.  Check out the [Arrays API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for more details.

While it seems it may be beyond the scope of your problem, you may also want to look into sorting algorithms to learn more about how that all works, rather than relying solely on the API.

Once sorted, you should be able to easily compare inwards from the boundaries to get your second lowest and second highest values.

Also, you shouldn't need to utilize the Math API, simple inequality operators should do the trick (< and >).

EDIT: While I recommend working on the problem yourself, here is a simple solution to the problem.  I place it here so if you get stuck you can reference this (and the associated comments) for guidance.

```
function SecondGreatLow(arr) {
  var i;
  var j;
  var lowest;
  var highest;
  var secondLowest;
  var secondHighest;

  //Sort Array
  arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  //Get Bounds
  //Since we sorted the array, and the default sort is in 
  //ascending lexicographical order, then we're guaranteed that 
  //our 'lowest' value is at index 0 and our 'highest' value is
  //at index arr.length -1.  Note that these values may be
  //equal.
  lowest = arr[0];
  highest = arr[arr.length - 1];

  //Search for second lowest.
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > lowest) {
      secondLowest = arr[i];
      break;
    }
  }

  //If we reach the end of the array, but didn't 
  //find a greater value, then, since the array is sorted,
  //we're guaranteed that all values in the array are equal.
  //Therefore, the required value comparisons have no meaning,
  //and we return 'undefined'.
  if (secondLowest === 'undefined') {
    return 'undefined';    
  }

  //Search for second highest, working backwards from the 
  //high end of the array until we reach our crossover point 
  //with the previous search.  Either some value > arr[i] is the
  //second highest, or arr[i] is, so there's no point in looking 
  //at values in the indices lower than i.
  for (j = arr.length - 1; j >= i; j--) {
    if (arr[j] < highest) {
      secondHighest = arr[j];
      break;
    }
  }

  return secondLowest + ' ' + secondHighest;

}

var result = SecondGreatLow([3,3,4,5,4,6]);
console.log(result);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62kh8ztc/2/)

Comment: Thank you!! It was mentioned by a commenter as well that I should sort the array, which is something I forgot I could do when I approached the problem.  I'll have a go and upload what I come up with.. I'm not gonna look at your solution until I've got it working by myself.

Total noob question: fiddle.net was linked in the other answer as well and it looks intuitive.. I assume the 'result' area is for the html and linked css and js implementation to be viewed.. so how about viewing the js console?  Is there a way to run code in that environment and see the console?

Comment: jsfiddle is a useful site for playing around with javascript, html, and css.  However, you're right, I didn't include an HTML interface, which would display in the "Result" pane.
  
Web browsers have developer controls that you can access that you give more details about what's running.  I typically do it by right clicking on a web page, and selecting "Inspect Element".  In the view that pops up at the bottom of the browser, there will be a tab for "Console", where you can view logged output.  (These instructions are for Firefox and Chrome).

Comment: What I ended up with is very close to your example :)  I'll have to remember that the sort method (function?) uses ascending lexicographic order by default to save some typing next time.  

Thanks again!!

Comment: Actually I think I found a snag in your implementation.. if we write arr.sort() without spelling out the function, the sorting method gets a little wonky when certain numbers are included in the argument array.. for example SecondGreatLow([1,42,42,180]) doesn't work properly since the array sorts to [1,180,42,42] when I run it..

Comment: @Manningham so you found an issue and implementation and the answer is still checked? :-D

Comment: haha oops, unchecked.  I wasn't sure if I was right on that point.. I've suggested an edit to straighten it out.  I don't like how I can only check one answer.. seems unfair if several are right.

Comment: Good catch, you're correct, we need to pass in a comparator function into sort.

I'll update the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You may create a priority queue limited by 2 elements, then feed it with all the array and pop the value, which would be the answer.

The trivial implementation would look like:

```
function UniqueNElementSortedQueue(length, comparison) {
    this.length = length;
    this.data = [];
    this.comparison = comparison;
}

UniqueNElementSortedQueue.prototype.push = function(v) {
    if (this.data.indexOf(v) > -1) {
        return;
    }

    this.data.push(v);
    this.data.sort(this.comparison);
    this.data.length = this.length;
};

UniqueNElementSortedQueue.prototype.popIfN = function() {
    if (this.data.length == this.length) {
        return this.data[this.length - 1];
    }
};
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fmfv67xy/

The solution is `O(N)` (one might argue that I have sorting internally and they would be right :-)) by number of operations and `O(N)` by additional memory (where `N` is linear to the "next-lowest/greatest" index value)

As the description does not define what to return if it was not sufficient data fed - my implementation returns `undefined`.

Comment: thanks for this, there are some things in here that I still need to learn like pop and I've only just touched on using this.. but I'll look into it and revisit this as I learn :)  jsfiddle.net is a pretty cool resource too, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, let me turn my comment into an answer, since I think it always helps to also worry about performance:

- Create 4 local variables:

  - ***largest*** and ***second_largest*** initialized to a number smaller than anything you'd expect in your array, or to the smallest possible value that your data-type can take on (-2^31 - 1)
  - ***smallest*** and ***second_smallest*** initialized to a number larger than anything you'd expect in your array, or the largest possible value for your data-type (2^31)
- Loop over your array once:

  - If you find a number larger than ***largest***, set ***second_largest*** to ***largest*** and ***largest*** to that number
  - If you find something smaller than ***largest*** but larger than ***second_largest***, set ***second_largest*** to that number
  - If you find a number smaller than ***smallest***, set ***second_smallest*** to ***smallest*** and ***smallest*** to that number
  - If you find something larger than ***smallest*** but smaller than ***second_smallest***, set ***second_smallest*** to that number
- When you're done with your loop, your answer is contained in ***second_largest*** and ***second_smallest***

Given how small your arrays seem to be, you might not notice much of a performance difference between this answer and the other suggested ones, but I think it's a good habit to get into to always keep this concern in the back of your head for every line of code you write. In this answer, you process every array element exactly once (i.e. the algorithm runs in [**O(n)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)), whereas adding a sorting step leads to every element being processed multiple times in a general case (the best sorting algorithms ([Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), for example) have an expected runtime of **O(n log n)**).

One thing to note:

@elclanrs mentioned a special case in his comment ([1, 1]), which according to the definition of the problem does not have a defined solution (multiple 1s all would be considered the largest number, so there is no second-largest). In this case, the algorithm above will still have ***second_largest*** and ***second_smallest*** set to their initial values.

Comment: Thanks!  This seems like a very practical solution and I'll keep the logic of it in mind.  I think I'll opt to just sort the array and work with the resultant order of elements for this challenge though since I'm not worrying about memory usage (is this what you meant by 'performance'?).

That's true the [1,1] case can't be solved by the guidelines of the challenge.. maybe I'll ignore that one?

Thanks again for your help.. is there a way I can rep you and the other answerers?  I tried the 'upvote' but I need 15 rep before I can do that.. I really appreciate the help though.

Comment: "whereas adding a sorting step leads to every element being processed multiple times in a general case (the best sorting algorithms (Timsort, for example) have an expected runtime of O(n log n))." --- constants matter, and `N` matters. For array of 2 (or 3) elements it does not matter if it's logarithmic, quadratic or even polinomial. So even for a real life task I would prefer sorting, just because it's more readable/maintainable than juggling with multiple vars and the same performant. http://jsfiddle.net/y9wurwd7/

Comment: @Manningham With "performance" I meant the speed with which the code will run. Sorting is a somewhat expensive (slow) operation. It will also likely use more memory (there are some sort algorithms that don't, but they tend to be even slower), which can be more or less of a concern depending on the platform you develop for (some mobile phones have very limited memory). For my own personal preference, I try to avoid sorting wherever I can.

Comment: @zerkms Absolutely correct that constants matter. But in this case, I'm pretty certain that the constants are much smaller for this answer than for calling a sort-algorithm, especially if you nest the if-statements correctly. I agree that for "small" problems readability can be more important than performance. It took me quite a few seconds to dig through the different methods implementing your logic, though. Especially if you look at just your calling code, its functionality is only explained by the class-name of your queue. In this case I definitely find simple linear code easier to read.

Comment: @Manningham As far as repping the answers here goes, don't worry about it for now! :) If you like, you can always come back to it later, when you get over 15. But the "Thank you" you already wrote is also just fine.